# Wronskian and Boundary condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Here is a partial differential equation, which is KdV equation,
$$
u_t-6uu_x+u_{xxx}=0
$$
with boundary conditions
$$
\psi\rightarrow e^{ikx},\quad \bar{\psi}\rightarrow e^{-ikx},\quad x\rightarrow\infty\\
\phi\rightarrow e^{-ikx},\quad \bar{\phi}\rightarrow e^{ikx}, \quad x\rightarrow-\infty
$$

My problem is someone gave me a claim that Wronskian of one of the solutions and its conjugate is $2ik$, i.e.,
$$
W(\psi,\bar{\psi})=2ik=-W(\psi,\bar{\psi})
$$
Is it reasonable determining Wronskian by boundary condition?

It's important since if the Wronskian is nonzero, I can represent a solution by another solution with transmission/reflection coefficient(related to $a(k)$, $b(k)$).
$$
\phi(x,k)=a(k)\bar{\psi}(x,k)+b(k)\psi(x,k)\\
\bar{\phi}(x,k)=-\bar{a}(k)\psi(x,k)+\bar{b}(k)\bar{\psi}(x,k)$$

And here $a(k)=\frac{W(\phi,\psi)}{2ik}$, $b(k)=-\frac{W(\phi,\bar{\psi})}{2ik}$.
I'm also not sure why the coefficients is in this way....

The claim comes from ''Ablowitz. Solitons, Nonlinear Evolution Equations and Inverse scattering.

Comment: Please provide more context. Where does this problem come from?

Comment: I append the source of this problem. Perhaps it's too hard for me to clarify whole frame. Thans for your advice.

Comment: I'm still confused. What do $\phi,\psi$ have to do with $u$ ?

Comment: $\phi$, $\psi$ are solutions of KdV equation under the boundary condition.